# jQuery got some trouble with IE 6?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I am working on a web app that requires a page to dynamically loadup a textbox and multi-select on selection inside another dropdown. For this I am trying to use jQuery.

I know it would be considered a punishable act, but I got to target IE6 as a possible browser.

The problem is I get an 'undefined', when I try to pickup a value using $('#id').val()

Here's some snippet:

```
function onFormLoad(){
  alert(typeof $);  // returns 'function'
  alert($('#eventId').val());  // returns undefined
}
```

I have a

```
<select id="eventId">...</select>
```

Any suggestions/pointers would be really great.

Thanks

Comment: Don't Code for less than 5% of the market. Current Statistics Show that IE 6 is only used by about 5% of the web users out there. Why worry and deal with the hassle for 5% of the market and has been declining every month. IE 6 is nearly dead. http://w3counter.com/globalstats.php?year=2010&month=10

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, I just want to say good luck.

Comment: @John Hartsock - IE6 accounts for 100% my market here at work. Sometimes you don't have a choice. The cost of upgrading IE an application for thousands of internal users will sometimes be considered to be too high.

Comment: @James Wiseman .... thats depressing news :(.  IE 7 released in Oct 18th of 2006.

Answer (score 0):

when do you call the function onFormLoad() ?
have you valid options inside your select with `value` attribute? Have you tried to set a `selected` attribute to the first option?

Comment: i call it from <body onload="onFormLoad()">

Answer (score 0):

Difficuly to tell from what you've given. A few pointers:

- Do you have other JS libs that might be conflicting?
- What happens if you change '$' to
  'jQuery' ?
- What do you get from
  `alert(jQuery.constructor );` ? I
  would expect to see 'function
  Function() {[native code]}' (see:
  http://jsfiddle.net/5aQjD/)
- Is this script above the jQuery
  script inclusion? If so, it may fail?
- Is your code in the `$(document).ready()` event? If not it may be executing before everthing is loading.

Comment: yes i get a 'function Function() {[native code]}' from alert(jQuery.constructor ); jQuery has been included before it is used.

Comment: Did you try the other points? You're maybe going to have to show us some more code.

Answer (score 0):

you could fall back to straight javascript:

```
alert(document.getElementById('eventId').value);
```

no it's not jQuery but it IS bulletproof..